# How to get the view refrence in local method

Tags: android, gridview

I M clicking an image on a grid view and trying to hide the images in it neighboe recursively but it is not happening. Code reaches the if statement but cant hide image

```
public class GridLayoutActivity extends Activity {

    GridView gridView;
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.right, R.drawable.right,
            R.drawable.right, R.drawable.left,
            R.drawable.left, R.drawable.left,
            R.drawable.left, R.drawable.up,
            R.drawable.left, R.drawable.up,
            R.drawable.down, R.drawable.right,
            R.drawable.up, R.drawable.right,
            R.drawable.up
    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

         gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                recursive(position,v);



            }

            private void recursive(int position,View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /* MobileArrayAdapter adapter=new MobileArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(), position);
                    System.out.println("Adapter set");
                    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);*/
                System.out.println(v);
                String imageName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(mThumbIds[position]);
                System.out.println(imageName);
                /*String up = getResources().getResourceEntryName(mThumbIds[position-3]);
                String down = getResources().getResourceEntryName(mThumbIds[position+3]);
                String right = getResources().getResourceEntryName(mThumbIds[position+1]);
                String left = getResources().getResourceEntryName(mThumbIds[position-1]);
                */
                if(imageName.equalsIgnoreCase("up"))//&&!down.equalsIgnoreCase("down"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)v;
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    try{
                    recursive(position-3, v);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(imageName.equalsIgnoreCase("down"))//&&!up.equalsIgnoreCase("up"))
                {
                    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)v;
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
                if(imageName.equalsIgnoreCase("left"))//&&!right.equalsIgnoreCase("right"))
                {System.out.println("M HERE");
                    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)v;
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                if(imageName.equalsIgnoreCase("right"))//&&!left.equalsIgnoreCase("left"))
                {
                    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)v;
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }



            }
        });
    }

    /*
    class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
    {
        Context context2;
        int position ;
        public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
             position =textViewResourceId;
             context2=context;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int positionn, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context2);
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

    }*/


}
```

Comment: won't work this way have to reset the adapter

Comment: are you sure that it enters if statement, try to debug your code.

Comment: Yes it enters in the first if statement and the image clicked in hide too then it goes to its recursive function and comes back and find the name and goes in that if condition but this time the object of view is old one so it does not hide the image this time